# fetch a particular row from SQL table in iOS?

Tags: ios, database, sqlite

I created a table using SQLite Manager(firefox plugin) with 4 columns and 5 rows.
Now i wanted to fetch an entire random row from that table with help of following code but it doesnt works as i have never used it before.. what am i possibly doing wrong??

```
-(NSDictionary *)fetchQuestionsWithRowID:(NSInteger)rowID withDbPath:(NSString *)dbPath
        {

      NSDictionary *questDic=[NSDictionary dictionary];
            sqlite3 *database=nil;
            if (sqlite3_open([dbPath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK)
            {
                const char *sql = "SELECT * FROM quizQuestions Where rowid=?";

                sqlite3_stmt *selectstmt;

                int result = sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &selectstmt, NULL);

                if(result != SQLITE_OK) {
                    NSLog(@"Prepare-error #%i: %s", result, sqlite3_errmsg(database));
                }

                if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &selectstmt, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
                {
// confused here
                    sqlite3_bind_text16(selectstmt, 1, &rowID, -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
                    while(sqlite3_step(selectstmt) == SQLITE_ROW) {

                        NSString *str = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt, 0)];

                        NSLog(@"string is %@",str);

                    }
                }
            }
            sqlite3_close(database);
            return questDic;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hemant, look at below code may be it help but you need to make that code according to your need, means need to correct table, etc:

```
 NSString* sqliteQuery = NULL;
    sqliteQuery = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT roomImage,bookID,roomName,floorID,roomDesc,id FROM roomTbl"];
    sqlite3_stmt* statement;
    if( sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, [sqliteQuery UTF8String], -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK )
    {
        while( sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW )
        {
            NSMutableDictionary* dict = [NSMutableDictionary new];
            NSData* data = nil;
            int length = sqlite3_column_bytes(statement, 0);
            data       = [NSData dataWithBytes:sqlite3_column_blob(statement, 0) length:length];
            [dict setObject:[Base64 encode:data] forKey:@"imageFloorBytes"];
            int idFR = sqlite3_column_int(statement, 1);
            [dict setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",idFR] forKey:@"BookingID"];

            [dict setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s",(const char*)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 2)] forKey:@"roomName"];
            [dict setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",sqlite3_column_int(statement, 3)] forKey:@"floorID"];
            [dict setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s",(const char*)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 4)] forKey:@"roomDesc"];
            [dict setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",sqlite3_column_int(statement, 5)] forKey:@"roomID"];
            [arr addObject:dict];
            [dict release];
        }
    }
    // Finalize and close database.
    sqlite3_finalize(statement);
```

Also, have you import your db? And, one more thing before doing any operation you must go for checking that the following file or db exists or not.

Hope, it'll sort-out your problem